# Django Api Project(Postman Methods Throwing Errors)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Just started learning on Api's and using Postman, so I am working on a Django Movie Rating App

Here are my models:

```
class Movie(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)



class MovieRating(models.Model):

    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])


    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'movie'))
        index_together = (('user', 'movie') )
```

So the error occurs when I try to run the the function that I have created so this function was to create a new rating for a movie if the rating did not exist and if the rating had existed then the program should update the rating of the user that's being made

Here is my model view set that has the code:

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def rate_movie(self, request, pk=None):

        if 'stars' in request.data:
            stars = request.data['stars']
            user = User.objects.get(id=1)
            movie = Movie.objects.get(id=pk)


            try:
                rating = MovieRating.objects.get(user=user.id, movie=movie.id)
                rating.stars = stars
                rating.save()
                serializer = MovieRatingSerializer(rating, many=False)
                response = {'message':'Rating has been updated', 'results': serializer.data}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


            except:
                rating = MovieRating.create(user=user , movie=movie)
                serializer = MovieRating(rating, many=False)
                response = {'message': 'Rating for movie has been created', 'results': 
                serializer.data}
                return Response(response, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

I shall add the picture for visual representation to what's happening on the Postman because maybe it might be me using the Postman wrong.[image: Screenshot of the Postman and error status code that I am getting]

Comment: What is your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add slash(/) to end of the url path whenever you request post method.
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/Api/moviewApi/movies/1/

Check [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/trailing-slash-in-restful-api) for your information

Comment: It is about how he define his url. Also there is no PageNotFoundError, so his url is correct.

Comment: @kamilyrb Thank you for comment. I know it's look like about how to define url. But I think this problem happens when omitting slash at the end of the url.